# Scrollviewer messing with focus

Tags: wpf, focus, scrollviewer

I have a window (with on-screen keyboard) on top of a user control of another window.

I want when the user clicks outside of the keyboard window, the keyboard window to be closed. For this I'm using the onlostFocus and Deactivated events, in which i call the method HideKeyboardWindow().

In the user-control I have a grid with 1 row.  When the keyboard is open and I click on the row of the grid, HideKeyboardWindow() isn't called. However, when I wrap the row with a ScrollViewer, then HideKeyboardWindow() is called.

Why is the scrollviewer messing with the focus?

Comment: there might be chance that you havent provided any width or height to your keyboard window and thats why its getting issue.please try setting minimum width to your keyboard grid row and then check

Comment: @AshokRathod The keyboard window has defined height and width.

Answer (score 0):

The `GotFocus` event is not a good event to use for your purpose because it can be raised at inappropriate times, such as when the user mouses over the inner controls of your keyboard for example. A better solution would be to simply attach an additional `MouseDown` handler to the parent control. When the parent handler receives the event, the user has clicked outside the keyboard control.

Comment: But the parent control is a grid which is in a user control which is in another window. There are a lot of parent controls. I can't add events to them all.

Comment: No, I mean the top level parent... I'm pretty sure that you only have one of those. Use a `MouseDown` handler in that control, and a `PreviewMouseDown` handler in the keyboard control so that that will be raised before the parent event.

Comment: the MouseDown event of the top level parent doesn't get called.

Comment: Try the `PreviewMouseDown` event.